# predetermine script input text

Tags: bash, shell-script, input

I have a script that automatically sets up an emailing server based off what I enter for the following

```
echo "Please enter your main domain: (Ex.: website.com)"
read DOMINIO
if [ $DOMINIO = "" ]; then
    echo "Enter the main domain of your server"
    echo "Run the script again"
    exit
fi
echo "Enter your main IP: (Ex.: 192.1.1.1)"
read SRVIP
if [ $SRVIP = "" ]; then
    echo "Enter main IP"
    echo "Run the script again"
    exit
fi

echo "Install Interspire? (yes/no)"
read INTERSPIRE

echo "Please enter a valid email address:)"
read VEMAIL
if [ $VEMAIL = "" ]; then
    echo "Enter valid email address:)"
    read VEMAIL
fi
echo -e "Script will begin installation in 5 seconds"
echo -e "Use CTRL + C to cancel!"
sleep 5
echo $DOMINIO > /tmp/domain.info
sed -i "s/ //g" /tmp/domain.info
sed -i "/^[ \t]*$/d" /tmp/domain.info
```

It then later installs Postfix DKIM key and asks me all the questions like secret password, name, email etc. How can I predetermine the text I will enter before the script starts?

Normally I just paste the following for the first script

```
daveis.com
5.196.24.211
yes
noreply@daveis.com
```

And then when Postfix command shows to create the key (`openssl req -new -key smtpd.key -out smtpd.csr`) I paste the following

```
somepass
somepass
somepass
GB
Berkshire
Newbury
DomainLLC
DomainLLC
mail.daveis.com
noreply@daveis.com
somepass
DomainLLC
somepass
somepass
somepass
somepass
GB
Berkshire
Newbury
DomainLLC
DomainLLC
mail.daveis.com
noreply@daveis.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use input from a file:

```
./your_script.sh < your_file_with_four_lines_of_input
```

or use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells):

```
./your_script.sh << EOF
daveis.com
5.196.24.211
yes
noreply@daveis.com
EOF
```